# Karma & Angular 5 - Component inheritance - Unit tests failing

Tags: angular, inheritance, karma-jasmine, multiple-inheritance

Running unit tests in Angular 5 application. I am only trying to run one single method from component(A).  Component(A) extends the BaseComponent.  The BaseComponent extends a private node package.
There is a method inside of Component(A)'s constructor that calls from those basecomponent, which then calls the private package:

```
this.pushSub(this.route.params
    .subscribe(params => this.onRouteParamsChanged(<routeType>params)));
```

The BaseComponent basically then passes this along to the package, which then runs the follow:

```
BaseComponent.prototype.pushSub = /**
 * @param {?} sub
 * @return {?}
 */
 function (sub) {
    this.subscriptions.push(sub);
};
```

Private package ^.  "subscriptions" is a local property inside of the private package.

When I run Karma, I cannot seem to get passed this point.  It gives me back the error:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

AND / OR

> "Property 'pushSub' is protected and only accessible within class 'BaseComponent' and its subclasses."

I do not need to run the entirety of Component(A), simply one single method, but cannot get passed this...
Below is the code I am attempting to use.

Attempt(1):

```
fdescribe("RequestViewComponent", () => {


let component: RequestViewComponent;
  let component2: ComponentFixture<RequestViewComponent>;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RequestViewComponent>;
  let mockProjectService,
      mockRequestService,
      mockTokenService,
      mockActivatedRoute,
      mockBaseComponent,
      mockPrivatePackageComponent,
      mockPrivatePackageComponent2,
      apiConfig: ApiConfig;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    console.log('start async'); // runs

mockActivatedRoute = {
  param: {
    subscribe: () => {
      ...
    }
  }
};
mockProjectService = jasmine.createSpyObj([
  '...'
]);
mockRequestService = jasmine.createSpyObj([
  '...'
]);
mockTokenService = jasmine.createSpyObj([
  '...'
]);
apiConfig = jasmine.createSpyObj(['apiConfig']);

mockPrivatePackageComponent = Object.setPrototypeOf(BaseComponent, PrivatePackageBaseComponent);

mockBaseComponent = Object.setPrototypeOf(RequestViewComponent.prototype
  .pushSub(mockActivatedRoute), PrivatePackageBaseComponent);



TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [FormsModule, RouterTestingModule, MatDialogModule],
  declarations: [Component(A)],
  providers: [
    { provide: ..., useValue: mockActivatedRoute },
    { provide: ..., useValue: mockProjectService },
    { provide: ..., useValue: mockRequestService },
    { provide: ..., useValue: mockTokenService },
    { provide: ..., useValue: apiConfig },
    { provide: BaseComponent, useClass: mockBaseComponent },
    { provide: PrivatePackageBaseComponent, useClass: mockPrivatePackageComponent },
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
  .compileComponents().then(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component(A));

    component = TestBed.createComponent(Component(A)).componentInstance;

  });

console.log('after async') // does not run

console.log('hello fixture', fixture) // does not run  
}))


describe('getCurState', () => { // fails

it('should call requestService.get', () => {
  mockRequestService.get.and.returnValue(of('New'));

  component.getCurState(); // cannot getCurState of undefined
  expect(mockRequestService.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
})

  })

})
```

I have also tried:

```
mockPrivatePackageComponent = Object.setPrototypeOf(BaseComponent.prototype
  .pushSub(mockActivatedRoute), PrivatePackageBaseComponent);

mockBaseComponent = Object.setPrototypeOf(RequestViewComponent.prototype
  .pushSub(mockActivatedRoute), PrivatePackageBaseComponent);
```

And:

```
mockPrivatePackageComponent = Object.setPrototypeOf(BaseComponent.prototype
      .pushSub(mockActivatedRoute), jasmine.createSpy(PrivatePackageBaseComponent));
```

And:

```
mockPrivatePackageComponent = Object.setPrototypeOf(BaseComponent, jasmine.createSpy(PrivatePackageBaseComponent));
```

...And basically every combination of those, along with a few hundred other things.

The main issue being, that "cannot read property push of undefined"... 
AS WELL, as (because of this?) fixture.createComponent(...) returns undefined no matter what I have tried.